# Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost:8080/auth/login

Tags: spring-security

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]почему не удается отправить пост запрос на адрес "/auth/registration"?

Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost:8080/auth/login[image: введите сюда описание изображения]